# Grails 3 Named Foreign Keys

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

We have an app developed initially under Grails 2, but we recently migrated to Grails 3. When we created our original tables, we renamed the generated foreign keys to something more human readable. Now under Grails 3, we are getting exceptions when trying to load/run the application.

We're using Grails 2.3.9, GORM 6.1.6.RELEASE, Hibernate5 6.1.6

> Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastoreServiceRegistry': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateDatastore' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastore': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Unable to execute schema management to JDBC target [alter table message add constraint FKnk6v4vlnstxdwedmm8wp6olvi foreign key (pref_id) references parent_ref]

This is complaining about the following SQL that it is attempting to run:

```
alter table message add constraint FKnk6v4vlnstxdwedmm8wp6olvi foreign key (pref_id) references parent_ref
```

But this is the existing (slightly redacted) table:

```
create table MESSAGE
(
    ID NUMBER(19)       not null primary key,
    VERSION NUMBER(19)  not null,
    PREF_ID NUMBER(19)  not null constraint FK_MESSAGE_PREF references PARENT_REF,
    TYPE CHAR(2 char)   not null,
)
/
```

The foreign key is already in place, just named differently. Grails/GORM/Hibernate used to recognize `FK_MESSAGE_PREF` as a valid foreign key, but now it does not. Is there a way for us to for the recognition of the existing foreign key?

Comment: Do you have dbCreate set for this datasource in application.yml or application.groovy? Try setting it to `dbCreate: 'none'` & boot

Comment: You shouldn't rely on the default DDL once you are in production. Database migrations should be used with `dbCreate: none`

Comment: We run our application with a user schema that only has DML rights. In the lower environments (DEV/TEST), running with `dbCreate:update` would allow us to catch missed SQL updates and add them to our production scripts. Changing to `dbCreate:none` allows the application to run, but now we are missing those checks. Running with `dbCreate: validate` gives a different error complaining about a missing `hibernate_sequence` which actually exists.